# Best way of filtering a generic collection when using lambda expressions?

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda

Is there any better way to filter a generic collection in .NET when using lambda expressions? Focus on readability but avoiding unnecessary code and following best practices when using lambda expressions or perhaps LINQ.

Here is some code for filtering a generic collection containing objects of type Pet and we want to get the minimum age of all objects with PetType = "Dog".

```
Module Module1

    Public Class Pet
        Public Name As String
        Public Age As Integer
        Public PetType As String
    End Class

    Sub Main()
        ' Create an array of Pet objects. 
        Dim pets As New List(Of Pet) From {
                                            New Pet With {.Name = "Barley", .Age = 8, .PetType = "Dog"}, _
                                            New Pet With {.Name = "Boots", .Age = 4, .PetType = "Dog"}, _
                                            New Pet With {.Name = "Jacky", .Age = 1, .PetType = "Cat"}, _
                                            New Pet With {.Name = "Whiskers", .Age = 2, .PetType = "Dog"}
                                        }

        ' Find the youngest dog by passing a  
        ' lambda expression to the Min() method. 
        Dim min As Integer = pets.Where(Function(pet) pet.PetType = "Dog").Min(Function(pet) pet.Age)

        ' Display the result.
        Console.WriteLine("The youngest dog is age " & min)

        ' This code produces the following output: 
        ' 
        ' The youngest dog is age 2
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can get any better than using the single call to the method `Where` that you are doing in practice. Did you have anything in particular that you were thinking might be inefficient?

Comment: Is this purely from an in-memory perspective or a DB querying perspective? Because they are 2 completely different challenges, also, is that around the number of records we are talking about? If so, any sort of improvement on what you have is going to be minuscule (microseconds, if any). If it's purely in-memory the spec of the machine it's running on is also a contributing factor...There is not enough context to answer the question correctly, really.

Comment: @James: I don't see a database anywhere in the above code... assuming there isn't one.

Comment: @Neolisk I know, however, more often than not people confuse LINQ to Objects with say LINQ to EF - I was just asking for clarification. The OP may be using this small example for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Sorry guys, this is not related to database/EF its only in-memory and you are probably right about the small performance gains changes to this code would do even if the collection in a production purpose would contain a lot more items, so this question is probably more about readability than performance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not more efficient, but slightly shorter and hopefully more readable:

```
Dim min As Integer =
  (From pet In pets Where pet.PetType = "Dog" Select pet.Age).Min
```

I merely converted your inline LINQ to query style.

Comment: Very good, inline LINQ would indeed improve readability of the code!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make this more idiomatic (and slightly more concise) in VB, you could use the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531251.aspx) clause as follows:

```
Dim minAge = Aggregate p In pets Where p.PetType = "Dog" Into Min(p.Age)
```